# Excluding results that are within same month in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables -- one, a `history` table that contains a log of some kind of entries, and another (let's call it `flags`) that contains columns about flags (for a certain account). Both tables contain account IDs.

I want to write a query that only extracts rows from the `flag` table if the account ID does not already have an entry for that month in the `history` table (e.g., in the `flag` table, an entry was entered on April 2, 2019 and in the `history` table, the account already had an entry recorded on April 1, 2019. The result is, the April 2nd entry should not be pulled up).

I have a query right now that basically looks like this:

```
SELECT *multiple column names* 
FROM flags 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT acc_id FROM history WHERE ...)
```

This is where I am stuck. With the subquery, I basically want to get the matches where the dates from both tables match (same month and year), and with the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, exclude the results from `flag` that are found in the subquery (essentially I only want results where the date for the entry is not from the same month)

The most important columns are:

- the account ID (to correctly associate each log entry to the right account)
- date (to only get rows where the month recorded is not already logged in the history table)

I initially used `MONTH()`, but that only extracts the month of the date. I need it to match both the month and the year because the history table contains a few years of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Do you want your result set to contain a first date record  per ID and month, year? Or do you want to eliminate all records that has same month and year per ID?

Comment: @ЯрославМашко The result should only grab results where records don't already exist in the "history" table. If an entry for an ID already exists in the "history" table for that month, year (subquery), I don't want it (WHERE NOT EXISTS). So the answer to your question, I believe is the latter. Thank you!

Comment: Always send Schema, sample data and the result you expect can make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *multiple column names* 
FROM flags 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM history 
  WHERE history.acc_id=flags.acc_id
   AND date_trunc('month', history.date) =
             date_trunc('month', flags.date)
)
```

The date_trunc function will work for postgres, which was one of the tags originally.  If you aren't using postgres, there may be a similar function in your database, it you could format the dates to just Year-month and compare the resulting strings.

Comment: this is a code dump. you're a relatively experienced user; please explain your answers.